# Kotlin Observer lambda syntax?

Tags: android, kotlin

I’m right now learning Kotlin for Android development coming from .NET C#. I have an issue regarding the Kotlin syntax, for example this:

```
 val nameObserver = Observer<String> { newName ->

            nameTextView.text = newName
  }
```

This code is taken from Android LiveData Documentation. I think Observer is a new object, without the new keyword, as it does not exists in Kotlin. My problem is the lambda part. Is this a property that is initialized in the object ? How do I know which property is initialized without naming them , are they taken in order ? What is supposed to be newName in this context, the nameObserver value or something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet you posted is called a [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). You're creating an object of interface type `Observer<String>` by specifying it as a lambda expression.

In your specific case `newName` is the parameter that is passed to the [onChanged method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Observer#onChanged(T)), and seeing as the code defines it as `Observer<String>`, is of type `String`.

Comment: you could also delete `newName ->` entirely, in which case you would then use    nameTextView.text = it, where `it` is the default assigned name, fwiw :)

Comment: Thanks for the explication and doc reference. In the kotlin docs "object" is also used in the syntax: object : IntPredicate . In the Android example "object" is not used. So I guess there is no need for "object" notation ?
Also, the lambda that I write basically overrides the abstract onChanged method ?

Comment: Yes, the lambda overrides the onChanged method. Kotlin allows this notation for any object type (interfaces or abstract classes) that only has a Single Abstract Methods (i.e. where the acronym SAM comes from). The syntax with `object : IntPredicate` is only needed when the type cannot be inferred through some other means if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax for a [SAM conversion.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)
It can be done because the Observer java interface only declares one method.

You can do this for Kotlin interfaces with [this syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces) in Kotlin 1.4+